# How should I deal with a large blocks of text in source code so that I the readability of the code is not compromised?

Tags: json, testing, go, software-design

Recently while fixing a bug in the system and thereof writing test for it we placed a large block of html string in the test source code. My only concern with that is that the large block are distractive and compromise the readability of the code.

Some, obvious, solutions for i that I came up with were:

- Move the individual block of text into separate text files which are read when the test is run. (My concern with this: efficiency and scalability)
- Move the blocks of text into a single json file and load it into a json object once (not quite confident about this solution. Overkill, if we only happen to have a few such tests with large blocks of text?)
- create a separate code file within the same package that would contain the blocks (same concerns as the previous one)
- stick with the current solution i.e. the large block of code inside the source code. And that it's not a big issue.

Language: Go

Questions:

- Which of the earilier solutions would be optimal? Or some other solution?
- Good to know: Is the solution to this concern dependent on the programming language that is in use?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a language depended issue. Having a large chunk of sting of any kind embedded inside the code compromise the readability of it.

As for a solution I would consider 2 aspects:
1. Is the string conent is really static - if you don't think it will ever change I believe putting it into another .go file is the best solution. Introducing more code to handle the loading of the content just makw things more complicated.
2. Deployment - one of the nicest thing about Go is having a single file you can run without any external dependencies. If you load the content of the string from external source you compromise that. The next person who will need to run the test will have to know about this file...

Answer (score 0):

There are several packages available which deal with this kind of problem, most prominently Jim Teeuwen's excellent [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata). What it basically does is to take input files and store the contents of those files into constants.
Of course, you can use this package.

Of course, you can do this manually. But, to declutter the actual code, I'd put those constants into separate files for that purpose. So basically, my `data.go` would look like this

```go
package yours

const (

FirstText =`
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam    
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.`

SecondText = `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit met, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam`
)
```

So, you can refer to those texts since they are global, but they do not clutter your code.

This approach should work with every programming language I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know Go but in any other language i worked with, we kept data (like big static text) outside of the source. first check if there is no framework that solves your problem - most languages have very powerful test ecosystem.

you are concerned about performance. have you measure the impact on the performance? it's just a few kb file